# Jacoco instrumentation error for Kotlin data class files

Tags: kotlin, maven, jacoco

I have a kotlin project that currently in the build time is showing a lot of error stack traces regarding Jacoco. By more investigation I found that a lot of them are regarding data classes. For example for something like:

```
data class FooDTO(val a: String, val b: String)
```

I am getting something like:

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting path/to/FooDtoMethodAccess with JaCoCo 0.8.10.202304240956/8ea9668.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:94)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader.defineClass(AccessClassLoader.java:73)
    at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader.defineAccessClass(AccessClassLoader.java:57)
    at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.MethodAccess.get(MethodAccess.java:276)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolverDataFetcher.<init>(MethodFieldResolver.kt:131)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolver.createDataFetcher(MethodFieldResolver.kt:98)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser$createObject$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.apply(SchemaParser.kt:126)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser$createObject$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.apply(SchemaParser.kt:46)
    at graphql.schema.GraphQLObjectType$Builder.field(GraphQLObjectType.java:207)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.createObject(SchemaParser.kt:124)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.parseSchemaObjects(SchemaParser.kt:85)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaParser.kt:109)
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.graphQLSchema(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:65)
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6059daa9.CGLIB$graphQLSchema$0(<generated>)
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6059daa9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a2c10eb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
06/07/2023 13:10:02     at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6059daa9.graphQLSchema(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at
```

This is my jacoco plugine configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

How can I get rid of those error messages?

Comment: which JDK version do you use? Second why have you defined the `report` to execute within a phase `prepare-package` and not kept the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what is the problem. These files are not exactly data classes, but they are auto generated probably by graphQL and the names ends with MethodAccess. To get rid of it you can easily exclude them from Jacoco:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*MethodAccess</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```